# How does changing were the recursive function is called change the result?

Tags: java, recursion

I am reading a book called "Think Java: How to think like a Computer Scientist", and I recently covered recursive methods.

```
public static void countdown(int n)
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("Blastoff!");
    } else {
        System.out.println(n);
        countdown(n - 1);
    }
}
```

This would be a normal recursive method used to count down to 0 and I understand what is happening, but if you make the recursive call before the System.out.println like this

```
if (n == 0) {
    System.out.println("Blastoff!");
} else {
    countup(n - 1);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

it counts the oppisote way, so If I gave the argument 3 for both of these condital statements the 1st one goes "3, 2, 1, Blastoff!" but the 2nd 1 goes "Blastoff, 1 ,2 ,3".... I don't understand how this works, can someone try to explain what is happening in this code that makes it count in the opposite way?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Stack Exchange network. The site you posted on (security) is about protecting data and networks from attackers - so your question is pretty off-topic. I've voted to move it to Stack Overflow where it will get a better answer.

Comment: I have voted likewise. user122144, why did you post the question here?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n == 0) {
    System.out.println("Blastoff!");
} else {
    countup(n - 1);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Thats just because you are placing `countdown(n-1)` before the `system.out.println(n);`

When you place before the `System.out.println(n)`, the method will keep calling from `countdown(n-1)` till it ends the call and the cursor goes to next system.out.println.

> So, that's how a recursion works, its like a self contained method,
>   one method calling another method......finally onces the last method
>   gets finished, its comes back to last-1 and then last-2 and the last-n

In your case, first it goes to `countdown(n-1)`, and keep caling the same method till it reachs, `n==0`. Once `n==0`, then all the method calls get back to their `System.out.println(n);`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `countup(n - 1)` before print, the print is *not reachable* until recursion stops. During recursion, numbers are pushed into **stack**. After recursion has been completed, the all numbers are popped out from stack.

We know, stack is **LIFO (Last In First Out)**. Since it push into the stack in order 3,2,1. That's why when the numbers are popped out from stack, they are in order 1, 2, 3.

But in the first approach, print is done before recursive call. That's why you are getting in order 3,2,1.